# Are there only finitely many maximal irreducible amenable subfactors at fixed finite index?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

A subfactor $N \subset M $ is maximal if it admits no non-trivial intermediate subfactors $N \subset P \subset M $.

**Question**: Are there only finitely many maximal irreducible amenable subfactors at fixed finite index (up to isomorphism)?

*Bonus question*: let $\alpha$ the index of a irreducible amenable subfactor.
Is there a maximal irreducible amenable subfactor of index $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Presumably, you are imagining fixing the isomorphism class of $N$ and $M$ as von Neumann algebras (otherwise, even for index=1, there are infinitely many). Another way of formalizing the question so that it has a chance of have a positive answer, is to ask for isomorphism classes of planar algebras.

Comment: What about subfactors of index 4? I think subfactors of affine type
$D_n$ are all maximal.

Comment: Dave Penneys says to me that each the $D_{n}^{(1)}$ subfactors decompose into intermediate subfactors isomorphic to $R^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}} \subset R$ (with $R$ the hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factor), but I have not verified this information, I will try to find a reference. 

Comment: If anyone know a reference containing the explicit intermediate subfactors lattice for all the $D^{(1)}_{n}$ subfactors, please post it here. 

Comment: Perhaps, the answer about $D^{(1)}_{n}$ is in the following paper:
http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs000130050078.pdf
but I have no access to it...

Comment: It says: "If $\Gamma$ is $D^{(1)}_n$ $n > 4$ or $D^{(1)}_\infty$, then $N\subset  M$ has the only one nontrivial intermediate
subfactor." in the proof they use that the Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: See also [Are there infinitely many amenable Hadamard-Petrescu subfactors?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/202567/34538)