# Existence of homogeneous single chain compositions of a given maximal subfactor?

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, finite-groups, lattices, subfactors

> All the [subfactors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor) here are **irreducible** inclusion of hyperfinite II$_1$ factors.

A subfactor $(N \subset M)$ is **Homogeneous Single Chain** ($HSC$) if its lattice of intermediate subfactors is a single chain:  $N=P_0 \subset P_1 \subset \dots \subset P_{n-1} \subset P_n= M$, with $(P_i \subset P_{i+1}) \simeq (P_0 \subset P_1)$.

We qualify such a subfactor by the **notation** $HSC^n_{(P_0 \subset P_1)}$, because it's a subfactor whose lattice is a single chain of length $n$ and whose intermediate maximal inclusions are all isomorphic to $(P_0 \subset P_1)$.

> **Question**: Is there a $HSC^n_{(P \subset Q)}$ subfactor for all maximal subfactor $(P \subset Q)$ and for all  $n>1$ ?

**Warning**: The subfactors given by the basic construction are not irreducible.

---

**Group-subgroup formulation**:

**Definition** : Let $(A \subset B)$ and $(C \subset D)$ be inclusions of groups, then $(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D)$ if $(A/A_B \subset B/A_B) \simeq (C/C_D \subset D/C_D)$, with $A_B$ the [normal core](http://groupprops.wiki-site.com/index.php/Normal_core) of $A$ in $B$.

**Remark** : In the finite group case, if $(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D)$ then $(R^B \subset R^A) \simeq (R^D \subset R^C)$, but the converse is false, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136021/is-there-a-purely-group-theoretic-reformulation-of-an-equivalence-of-subgroups) ($R$ is the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor).

**Definition**: An inclusion of groups is $HSC^n_{(A \subset B)}$ if its lattice of intermediate subgroups is a single chain of length $n$ and if its intermediate maximal inclusions of groups are all $\sim$ to $(A \subset B)$.

> **Question**: Is there a $HSC^n_{(A \subset B)}$ inclusion for all maximal inclusion $(A \subset B)$ and for all  $n>1$ ?

**Remark**: An inclusion of group $(A \subset B)$ is given (up to $\sim$) by a transitive permutation group $G$ of degree $d = [A:B]$ (i.e. $G$ is the image of the coset representation and $(A \subset B) \sim (G_1 \subset G$)).
Idem a maximal inclusion of groups is given (up to $\sim$) by a primitive permutation group.

**Notation**: A transitive group $G$ is $HSC^n_{M}$ (with $M$ a primitive  group) if $(G_1 \subset G)$ is $HSC^n_{(M_1 \subset M)}$.

**Experimental answer**: **Yes**, if we restrict to the transitive groups of degree $\le 30$.
More precisely, let $G_{d,r}$ be the $r$-th transitive group of degree $d$ given by the [GAP Data Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/trans.html)  :

```
gap> TransitiveGroup(5,4);  
A5
```

**Remark**: $G_{d,1}$  is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$

The primitive groups of deg. $\le 5$: $G_{2,1}$ ;  $G_{3,1}$, $G_{3,2}$ ; $G_{4,4}$, $G_{4,5}$ ; $G_{5,1}$, $G_{5,2}$,$G_{5,3}$, $G_{5,4}$, $G_{5,5}$.

The following tables gives the number of $HSC^n_{G_{d,r}}$ transitive groups of degree $\le 30$ related to the primitive group $G_{d,r}$, with $n>1$, and the first examples.

$\begin{array}{c|c}
 &G_{2,1}&G_{3,1}&G_{3,2}&G_{4,4}&G_{4,5}&G_{5,1}&G_{5,2}&G_{5,3}&G_{5,4}&G_{5,5} \newline 
                         \hline
2 &2&4&9&18&30&8&15&31&1&5  \newline
                         \hline
3 &15&152&476                \newline
                         \hline
4  &597   
\end{array} $

$\begin{array}{c|c}
 &G_{2,1}&G_{3,1}&G_{3,2}&G_{4,4}&G_{4,5}&G_{5,1}&G_{5,2}&G_{5,3}&G_{5,4}&G_{5,5} \newline 
                         \hline
2 &G_{4,1}&G_{9,1}&G_{9,3}&G_{16,63}&G_{16,195}&G_{25,1}&G_{25,4}&G_{25,8}&G_{25,192}&G_{25,196}  \newline
                         \hline
3 &G_{8,1}&G_{27,1}&G_{27,8}                \newline
                         \hline
4  &G_{16,1}   
\end{array} $

These tables show the existence of all the $HSC^n_{G_{d,r}}$ transitive groups of degree $\le 30$.

**Remark**: There is one and only one $HSC^2_{G_{5,4}}$ transitive group: $G_{25,192}$, of order $46656000000$, whereas $G_{5,4} \simeq A_5$ is order $60$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** by free compositions:

**Theorem**:  Let $N \subset M$ be an irreducible finite index subfactor with $P$ an intermediate subfactor ($N \subset P \subset M$) such that $N \subset M$ is a free composition of $N \subset P$ and $P \subset M$.
If $L$ is another intermediate subfactor $N \subset L \subset M$, then  $N \subset L \subset P$ or  $P \subset L \subset M$.

I've just written a proof in this [short note](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0Wl81MnhUODBhM3c/edit?usp=sharing).
This result was already in this [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5656) of Zhengwei Liu
(thm 2.11 p 9) with a different proof.
(Note that the two last paragraphs of my proof can be avoided by using Liu's thm 4.1 p18)

Now, thanks to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123600936073) of Sante Gnerre, there always exists a finite index irreducible subfactor realizing a free composition of two given finite index irreducible subfactors.

**Conclusion**: Given a finite index irreducible maximal subfactor $(P\subset Q)$, there exists a $HSC_{(P\subset Q)}^n$ subfactor for all $n$, it suffices to take free compositions of $(P\subset Q)$.

**Remark**: A free compostion of group-subgroup subfactors is not group-subgroup in general, so it's still open at this level, and harder (see the last remark of the section "group-subgroup formulation" above).

**Remark**: For non-free compositions, a sufficient condition for the theorem is true (i.e. "no extra intermediate") is : $\alpha \xi_i \overline{\alpha}$ irreducible for all $i \neq 0$ (see notation [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0Wl81MnhUODBhM3c/edit?usp=sharing)) [observation of Zhengwei and me].

**Remark-questions**: a free composition (with a non-trivial subfactor) is not a "finite depth" subfactor, so we can also ask, given a *finite depth* finite index irreducible maximal subfactor $(P\subset Q)$:
- Is there a finite depth $HSC_{(P\subset Q)}^n$ subfactor for all $n$?  (or equivalently, a finite depth "quotient" of the free composition subfactor (planar algebra) with "no extra intermediate", see the remark above).
- If $(P\subset Q)$ is depth $r$, what's the minimal depth of a $HSC_{(P\subset Q)}^n$ subfactor?