# An upper bound for the maximal subgroups at fixed index?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, finite-groups, subfactors

Let us call a **subgroup** an injective homomorphism between groups.

> **I warn the reader that a *subgroup* designates here an inclusion $(H \subset G)$, not $H$ alone.**

A subgroup $H \subset G$ is **maximal** if for all intermediate subgroups $H \subset K \subset G$, then $K=H$ or $G$.

Let $\sim$ be the **[equivalence of subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136021/is-there-a-natural-definition-of-equivalence-for-groups-inclusions-inner-to-the)** (defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136021/is-there-a-natural-definition-of-equivalence-for-groups-inclusions-inner-to-the)).
Note that the maximality is invariant under $\sim$.

Let $n$ be a fixed integer. For each equivalence class of index $n$ maximal subgroups, we choose a representative  $(H \subset G)$ with $G$ of minimal order. Let $R_{n}$ be the set of all these representatives.

**Interrelated questions :**

- Does $R_{n}$ is a finite set ?
- $\forall (H \subset G) \in R_{n}$, is $ord(G)$ bounded ?
- Is $G$  always a finite group ? A counter-example ?

**Original motivation**: [What's the list of all the maximal subgroups at index $6$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135806/are-subfactor-planar-algebras-hard-to-classify-at-index-6/135994#135994) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm absolutely ignorant about subfactors, but if I correctly understand what you said [there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136021/6451) (the theorem in the question), the answer to all three questions is yes, even with non maximal subgroups.

Namely, let $H\subset G$ be of finite index $n$. Since the intersection $K$ of all conjugates of $H$ in $G$ has index dividing $n!$ in $G$ (it is the kernel of the obvious morphism $G\to S_n$) and is of course normal in $G$, you have $(H\subset G)\sim (H/K\subset G/K)$.

The case of maximal subgroups is then about [*primitive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_permutation_group) (in particular transitive) finite permutation subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: Thank you @BS. for this nice answer. It's wonderful that the problem reduced to primitive permutation groups. I found this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305002541) in the wiki-page you link, where all is explained in details and classified for n<2500 (also 4096 in a more recent paper).

Comment: The last question to answer is whether or not some of these objects give *equivalent* maximal subgroups ?

Comment: @Sebastien : there seems to be a criterion for von Neumann equivalence in the IMRN article http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2002/34/1791.short but I don't have access to it.

Comment: Yes @BS. You can access to this paper [here](http://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/2002/2.ps) via a [ps2pdf converter](http://www.ps2pdf.com). The group theoretic characterization of the *equivalence* is quite technical, so that it seems not obvious to answer this last question for a non *group theorist*.

Comment: BS: Your answer works, but only for finitely-generated groups. In the infinitely-generated case $Hom(G,S_n)$ could be infinite and an answer would require opening up the definition of "equivalence" in the OP. Another caveat is that, on the face of it, the OP uses very unusual definition of a "subgroup." With this definition, $Z^2$ contains infinitely many subgroups of index 1. Maybe this does not matter though (again, it depends on the definition of equivalence).

Comment: Misha: I don't understand your comment. The group $G$ isn't fixed. Instead, one is considering the class of all inclusions of index $n$, $(H\subset G)$, up to an equivalence relation that (according to the theorem in http://mathoverflow.net/q/136021/6451) is coarser than the conjugacy relation on transitive subgroups of $S_n$; regarding this last assertion, and your index $1$ remark, I admit that I took for granted that isomorphic inclusions (in the category of group morphisms) are equivalent, which should be obvious to a subfactor theorist. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: Indeed, up to isomorphism, there is only one inclusion of hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factors at index 1. The last question is: Is this *equivalence relation* strictly coarser than the conjugacy relation, on primitive subgroups of $S_{n}$ ?