# Are there infinitely many amenable Hadamard-Petrescu subfactors?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

The [complex Hadamard matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Hadamard_matrix) of dimension $n$ are used to build index $n$ subfactors through the commuting square construction.   For more details, see the paper [Subfactors and Hadamard Matrices](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.1128) by W. Camp and R. Nicoara.

In his [PhD dissertation](http://www.worldcat.org/title/existence-of-continuous-families-of-complex-hadamard-matrices-of-certain-prime-dimensions-and-related-results/oclc/38594777) (1997), M. Petrescu has built three continuous families of complex Hadamard matrices of dimension $7$, see these matrices in [this link](http://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/~karol/hadamard/index.php?h=0702).

**Question**: Are there infinitely many isomorphism class of amenable subfactors coming from these (dimension $7$) Hadamard matrices of Petrescu?

*Remark*: A subfactor of index $7$ must be maximal (which is not necessarily true for the prime numbers greater than $8$). So if the question admits a positive answer, then the index $7$ would be the first known index allowing infinitely many non-isomorphic maximal amenable subfactors (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132875/34538)).

Comment: The assumption "amenable" is useful because in p14 of the paper [A finiteness result for commuting squares of matrix algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404301) of R. Nicoara:  << A main point
of interest in this  (Petrescu’s) result is that it can produce one-parameter families
of non-isomorphic subfactors with (the same index $n$ and) the same graph, conjectured to be
$A_∞$ >>